# U(1) local gauge transformation for Dirac spinor field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory

How can we define U(1) local gauge transformation for Dirac spinor field?, like scalar fields?

Comment: The Lorentz representation of a field has no impact on its gauge representation, and vice versa.

Comment: Can we say $\psi' = \exp{(-ie\lambda(x))} \psi $ for spinor fields?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.